# 403 error when opening new browser tab in Azure Portal

Tags: azure

In the Azure Portal, in certain scenarios when it prompts me to open a URL in a new tab, I get a 403 error.

"Error 403 - This web app is stopped"

I have followed the help link on that page (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2016/01/05/azure-web-apps-error-403-this-web-app-is-stopped/), but none of these issues (see footnote for issues) apply to me.

Specific examples of when I get this message:

In an app service > App Service Diagnostics > Collect Memory Dump: the report is available to view in a pop-out URL. When I click on the link, it opens a new browser tab and I can see from the url that it's attempting an oauth sign-in, which eventually displays the 403 page.

In an app service > App Service Editor (Preview), when I click on the "Go" link, as before, it opens a new browser tab and I can see from the url that it's attempting an oauth sign-in, which eventually displays the 403 page.

In both cases, it redirects to a https://****.sso.azurewebsites.net url which displays the 403 message.

Any suggestions?

**Footnote:** According to that url, there are 3 conditions that can cause this error to be presented.

- The site has reached a billing limit and your site has been disabled.
- The Website has been stopped in the portal.
- The Azure Website has reached a resource quota limit that applies to either Free or Shared scale modes.

Comment: What role you have for this resource or subscription level, are you an owner or a contributor ?

Comment: Good point @IvanIgnatiev - I am a Contributor. I've requested Owner access rights so I'll check that. Feel free to add your comment as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Ivan's comment, I checked my role settings. I was a Contributor for this Azure subscription. Since I changed it to an Owner (via Access control IAM > Role Assignments), it now works as expected.

It's frustrating that this is not made obvious in the Azure Portal.

Comment: to be more secure: if you are a Contributor at subscription level, try to ask to be an owner of App Service resource or App Service's Resource Group only, like this you will have Ownership on App Service without impacting other resources in your subscription

Answer (score 1):

In my case, There were network IP restrictions applied to the site. So I was getting the same error above from my home network. You can check the rules by going to the **properties** tab. To modify, go to **Networking**->**Configure access restrictions**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only getting the error when you open a new tab, it could be a problem with the maximum number of connections.

Are you running in debug mode? For Basic and below the maximum number of debug connections is 1.